# different versions of webpack are needed, npm start throws an error

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-scripts

I have created years ago a react project using create-react-app. In my react project i have a dependency to the react-scripts@3.4.3 npm package. But i also have a dependency to a npm package that needs react-scripts@4.0.3 package (so different versions). When running `npm install`, i don't have any issue. But when running the command `npm start`, i have this error prompted :

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.42.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  D:\Dev\Foo\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.44.2)
```

So from what i understood, the react-scripts@3.4.3 that i have in my package.json needs webpack@4.42.0, while another package need the webpack@4.44.2 version (which is the installed one by npm). I checked with the command `npm ls webpack` to see what versions of webpack are needed in the tree. And it confirms that.

My knowledges about npm is not that good. I thought it could be "smart" enough to install multiple version of the same package, but it seems to not be the case.

What can i do to fix that please ?

Also explanations are really appreciated. Knowing how a tool, that i'm using every day, works is a good thing.

Comment: It _is_ smart enough to install multiple versions of the same package, which is why that's what has happened. But CRA warns you about that because it can cause hard-to-debug errors. Why not just upgrade the project to react-scripts@4 (5 is out now, 3 is rather old at this point)?

Comment: Oh ok, my bad then. So the "error" is more on the CRA. Will try to upgrade the version of react-scripts it would be better then. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

create .env file in your root directory and add this line that file

SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true

this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes with the newest versions of React, this will solve the issue.